# Custom output cache provider and HttpContext.Current.Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, outputcache, httpcontext.cache

I have a shared hosting space that give me 1G space. In the other hand, it is a shared hosting and I have not more resources (such as memory). So, I decide to use a file-based output cache provider. I googled the issue and find some useful solutions. And here is mu question:

Does changing the output cache provider, change the `HttpContext.Current.Cache` provider too? And if not, how can I change it? I want to use a file-based cache system for `HttpContext.Current.Cache` too. I googled the issue, but all I found is about output cache provider.
Thanks in advance.